# Why the java code for connecting to JMS service is not compiling?

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

I have been using the GlassFish server to work on project to connect with JMS service with my java code. 
I have created the connectionFactory, queue and Topic as described below.

```
1. jms/GlassFishBookConnectionFactory connectionfactory
2. jms/GlassFishBookQueue queue
3. jms/GlassFishBookTopic
```

Here is my java code to connect to JMS service for the above connection. I have been following the given url's steps to work on it. http://www.packtpub.com/article/setting-glassfish-jms-and-working-message-queues
I am just started to study the JMS service. I am not perfect working on it. I have downloaded the java.jms jar file and extracted it.

```
package net.ensode.glassfishbook;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.*;

public class MessageSender
{
  @Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishBookConnectionFactory")
  private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
  @Resource(mappedName = "jms/GlassFishBookQueue")
  private static Queue queue;

  public void produceMessages()
  {
    MessageProducer messageProducer;
    TextMessage textMessage;
    try
    {
      Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
      Session session = connection.createSession(false,
        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
      textMessage = session.createTextMessage();

      textMessage.setText("Testing, 1, 2, 3. Can you hear me?");
      System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
        + textMessage.getText());
      messageProducer.send(textMessage);

      textMessage.setText("Do you copy?");
      System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
        + textMessage.getText());
      messageProducer.send(textMessage);

      textMessage.setText("Good bye!");
      System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
        + textMessage.getText());
      messageProducer.send(textMessage);

      messageProducer.close();
      session.close();
      connection.close();
    }
    catch (JMSException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new MessageSender().produceMessages();
  }
}
```

Currently when i compile this code. i am getting the error like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.ensode.glassfishbook.MessageSender.produceMessages(MessageSender.java:26)
    at net.ensode.glassfishbook.MessageSender.main(MessageSender.java:58)
```

Comment: Well, that is not a compilation error its a runtime error..The code compiles but you have a NullpointerException - most likely since your running the code out of container...

Comment: Your title is missleading, the code compiles but it fails while running with a `NPE`. Which line is 26 in your code?

Comment: @A4L How can i make this workable. I am just started coding the java and JMS together. What could be its solution.

Comment: @Robinhood from what I undersand from the article is that there is a tool that comes with glassfish that you can use to run your standalone application as if it were running inside the glassfish application container. You will need to export your application/class to a jar file and then use that tool to run your application. See what I have quoted from the article in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the resources are not getting injected to your class because you run it as a standalone application.

Quoting the article you have linked:

> Before delving into the details of this code, alert readers might have noticed that this class is a **standalone Java application** as it contains a main method. As this class is standalone, it executes **outside the application server**. In spite of this, we can see that some **resources are injected into it**, specifically the connection factory and queue. The reason we can inject resources into this code, even though it runs outside the application server, is because **GlassFish includes a utility called appclient**.
>
> This utility allows us to **"wrap" an executable JAR file and allows it to have access to the application server resources**. To execute the previous code, assuming it is packaged in an executable JAR file called jmsptpproducer.jar, we would type the following command in the command line:
>
> ```
> appclient -client jmsptpproducer.jar
> ```

Try to run the application as stated above.

Comment: in general, just add jars to `jmsptpproducer` so that it can be invoked with `java -jar jmsptpproducer.jar`?  But, how would another class use the producer?

Answer (score 0):

Use name instead of mappedName. name is the JNDI name, mappedName is product specific name. See the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html)

@Resource(name="jms/GlassFishBookConnectionFactory")
public static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;